# ArgumentError: is not a recognized provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using figaru to keep my details private and not upload it to heroku.

When I push my app to heroku I get the following message

```
 -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   ArgumentError:  is not a recognized storage provider
```

**carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider =>  ENV["provider"],
      :aws_access_key_id =>  ENV["aws_access_key_id"],
      :aws_secret_access_key =>  ENV["aws_secret_access_key"]
    }
    config.fog_directory = 'website-name-prod' if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_directory = 'website-name-dev' if Rails.env.development?
end
```

**application.yml**

```
provider : AWS
aws_access_key_id : ************
aws_secret_access_key : ********************
```

Comment: regarding figaro documentation you should use command `figaro heroku:set -e production` . Did you do this?

Comment: I did not realize there is a addtional command. The syntax looks like it should be "figaro heroku:set -e production -a website-name" ?

Comment: or `figaro heroku:set -e production --remote website-name`